# how to fix the icon of this in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: icons, customization, icon-themes

[image: Volume Icon]

how do I fix this icon when I change my volume? It just looks so ugly.
im using a theme called "Elemento Dark". but even when i change my both icon and application theme back to default ones, and restart gnome(even reboot machine) this still remains the same.

Comment: Do you know which theme you are using?

Comment: "elemento dark" application theme and Gruvbox icon theme, but changing them back to default doesn't work.